# How to join 2 tables and display the desired column values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 2 tables namely studentform and cities. cities table has 2 columns 'id' and 'name'. I am storing the 'id' from cities table in my studentform column 'city'

I have to display list of students with their cities by joining 'studentform' and 'cities' table.

how to join these 2 tables and fetch city name from cities table for corresponding id stored in 'city' column of studentform table.

I tried the below method, but the in the output list, the city column shows the 'id' value. How to change it to display the 'name'?

```
class StudentForm < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student_form
end
```

Comment: There is no clear question here. Is the desired behavior just that the name of the city corresponding to the saved id to be selected by default on the select dropdown?

Comment: No. thats not my question. the default selected function is working fine. but how to display the name of the city in the list view instead of the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I right, that you want each `StudentForm` to belong to **one** `City`? Only then, you can store city_id in `StudentForm`. But then your models would be:

```
class StudentForm < ActiceRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city

  delegate :name, to: :city. prefix: true
end

class City < ActiceRecord::Base
  has_many :student_forms
end
```

and you could access the city's name of a form with

```
form = StudentForm.first
puts form.city.name
```

or

```
puts form.city_name
```

In your example, each `StudentForm` has_many `:cities`, so `City` needs a reference to `StudentForm` (a column `student_form_id`).

Comment: SELECT s.firstname, c.name
  FROM student_forms s
  INNER JOIN cities c ON c.id = s.id
  LIMIT 0 , 30

This is what I am looking for- I want my index to display the student name and city_name. At present my index view is showing the student name and city_id. Now, how to display the city_name for the respective student by its city_id?

Comment: `student_form.city` is an instance of model `City`, so `student_form.city.name` is the attribute `name` of the `City` belonging to `student_form`.
I think, this is what your looking for. (but the join in your select has to be `ON c.id = s.city_id`)

Comment: In Rails you often don't have to care about the SQL, it's done by ActiveRecord and AREL.

Comment: Well now it's getting a bit more sofisticated, great for Rails. `collection_select` uses a set of objects and a value method and a label method of this model. Normally `StudentForm` has no `city_name` but you could `delegate` this to `City`: In `class StudentForm` say `delegate :name, to: :city, prefix: true` and you have a `city_name` method of `StudentForm` you can use in `collection_select`

Comment: getting an idea. but still stuck up. all i need is to display the text_method as the result in my list of students as i am using collection_select. 
Ex: studentname: harry, city: 1(value_method)
This wat is displaying now in the list of students or index page.
Whereas, i want my student list to display the text for that id.
  studentname: harry, city: washington(text_method)

Comment: ok. well, now if i have to create a method to show the city name in my index and show(profile) page. how to do that? Like for example
  def city_name
   @city = ....(the selected text_method(city.name) value)
  end
wat should be the code to display the selected name of city for a particular student?

Comment: `student.city_name` is defined when you use the delegation.